# Enviar un "token" en una cabecera http

Tags: html, angularjs, spring-boot

Actualmente tengo un microServicio creado con SpringBoot que hace un redirect a una página de AngularJS.

El microServicio consiste en recoger unos datos, llamar al netPlus (plataforma de pago) y sea ok o ko, hacer una re dirección a la página de angularJS.

La arquitectura de la aplicación ya está en pro y no se va a tocar, la solución es que el AngularJS **detecte que se ha pasado por el microServicio** de alguna manera y de no haber pasado por ahí, que no intenten acceder a la página de confirmación de pago pegando una URL en el navegador.

He pensado en poner a la cabecera HTTP una especie de "token" y que se envíe al cliente ->

```
 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/respuesta", consumes = { "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            "application/json" }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ModelAndView controlRespuestaNetPlus(Respuesta datos,
            @RequestParam(value = "id", required = true) String idPago, RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

        if (s_log.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
            s_log.log(Level.FINEST, "--->  SERVICIO RES");
        }
        printParameters(datos);
        try {
            URLRespuesta salida = ion.procesarRespuestaNetPlus(datos, idPago);
            String url = salida.getUrl();
            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("token", "token");
            // Tratamiento en la url a redireccionar
            url = URLRedirect(salida);
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + url);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Control de errores
            URLRespuesta objSalida = e.getDatosRespuesta();
            if (objSalida.getUrl().contains("ok")) {

                s_log.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage());
                if (s_log.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
                    s_log.log(Level.FINEST, "Error en en la llamada");

                }
            } else {
                s_log.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage());
                if (s_log.isLoggable(Level.FINEST)) {
                    s_log.log(Level.FINEST, "Error en procesar");
                }

            }
            // Tratamiento en la url a redireccionar
            return new ModelAndView("redirect:" + URLRedirect(e.getDatosRespuesta()));
        }
    }
```

El `redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("token", "token");` Debería poner una especie de token que debería poder interpretar el angular, además debería de ser de 1 solo uso, es decir, si recargas, no podrías volver a ver la página de confirmación porque debería expirar.

Finalmente con el F12 después de ejecutar el código ->

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es la pestaña network para ver si estoy enviando el "token" a priori yo no lo veo(quizás aquí no se ve eso).

La pregunta es:

¿Cómo veo el token que mando y como detecta el cliente que se le ha enviado ?
Gracias.

Comment: Al hacerse una redirección se pierden los atributos, puedes usar una cookie para guardar el token

Comment: Saludos @PabloLozano, pero estoy usando el redirectAttributes, que es para guardar los atributos en la re-dirección, me fijé de aquí:http://zetcode.com/springboot/flashattribute/ El problema es que para recogerlo usa también java, pero yo uso angularJS

Comment: Y ese es el problema: el navegador directamente ejecutará la redirección, perdiendo cualquier información recibida

Comment: Pero si el usuario tiene desactivadas las cookies no puedo comprobar si me ha venido del backend

Comment: La otra solución es que la redirección añada el token en la URL, como parámetro, si trabajas con HTTPS no sería problemático

Comment: Podrían copiar la url y pegarla en el navegador en cualquier otra ocasión para acceder

Comment: Pues sin cambiar mucho el código no se me ocurre otra solución. Lo lógico sería que mandases un token de un sólo uso a AngularJS, y éste último lo usase para hacer una llamada extra a backend para saber que el token es correcto y actual. Una vez comprobado el token, éste es "olvidado" por el backend y devolvería un error si se intentara reutilizar

Comment: podría valer la solución de que al poner en la cabecera http que sale : Origin: null, pusiera origin: "miServidor" o algo asi ?